# What is the best way to ask for a draw in chess?

Tags: word-choice

I play in chess tournaments in China, and in the past, I've been unable to ask my opponent for a draw because I didn't know how to say it in Chinese off the top of my head (and we can't use electronic devices during play, so I can't whip out Pleco).  It's important that I ask for a draw accurately.

It seems the correct word is: [平局](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%B3%E5%B1%80) (píngjú) = draw, tie.  However, I'm wondering how to accurately phrase the question.  I would guess 你想平局吗？ but it's not quite right: it's not clear that I'm making a draw offer.  Maybe I could say 我提供平局, but I'm not sure.

**Question**: What is the best way to ask for a draw in chess?

Comment: Could you explain the exact situation? I believe English has its own local-related expression for this. And the Chinese version would be totally different from the literal translation.

Comment: After making a move in chess, in English I would ask "would you like a draw?" or I might state "I offer a draw".  If the opponent agrees before their next move, the game is then a draw.

Comment: Well, I don't know any one-short-sentence in Chinese to express this. Maybe "就算平局吧"。Let's count (this) as a draw.

Comment: I would say 我提议和棋，你同意吗

Answer (score 3):

Orally, depending on the situation, you could use the following phrases

> 咱们要不和了吧？
>
> 我不想下了，就算平局吧。

和 means 讲和，which just implies 平局。The second expression would be more casual and is suggested to be used with close friends.

Above is how you would ask for a draw if the situation is really tied and both of you are tired, if you are feeling that you are losing, of course you would say

> 咱不下了，我认输了！

Comment: Not meaning to be a bother, but is 了 in 咱们要不和了吧 pronounced le or liǎo?

Comment: @Becky李蓓 le is the case.

Comment: That is the gist, but I think in the scenario the expressions should be a little bit formal.

Answer (score 1):

As I typed in the comment, I would say

> 我提议和棋，你同意吗？////
>   I offer a draw, would you like it?

To avoid confusion, 和棋 might be the professional terminology for "draw" in chess [as I self-studied]. 提议 means "suggest", or in your case, "offer".